# Bash SubMenu Does not Exit back to Parent

Tags: bash, sh, ubuntu-16.04

I am trying to build out a "categorized" `dialog` for some bash scripts on my local machine.

What I would like to do is have something like the following "menu" structure

```
Parent Menu1
    Child 1
    Child 2
    Child 3
Parent Menu2
    Child 1
    Child 2
    Child 3
```

etc.

All that is happenning right now, is if I select `Parent Menu1`, and then select the EXIT from it the child menu that is created, it only refreshes the child menu.

How can I get it to simply go "back" to the `Parent Menu1`?

**CODE**

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ "$(whoami)" != "root" ]; then
    echo "Only root can do this.";
    exit 1;
else

    DWIDTH=40
    DHEIGHT=13
    DIR="$( cd "$( dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" )" && pwd )"; 

    # Silently install dialog
    apt -y install dialog >/dev/null 2>&1

    cmd=(dialog --clear --backtitle "Get You Online Commander" --title "Get You Online Commander" --menu "What would you like to do?" $DHEIGHT $DWIDTH 6)

    options=(0 "Install/Update the Commander"
             1 "Manage Sites"
             99 "EXIT")

    while true; do

        choices=$("${cmd[@]}" "${options[@]}" 2>&1 >/dev/tty)

        # If cancelled, drop the dialog
        if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
            dialog --clear --title "Exit Commander" --infobox "We'll see you next time." 7 $DWIDTH
            sleep 2;
            clear;
            exit;
        fi;

        for choice in $choices; do
            case $choice in
                0)
                    #install/update GYO Commander
                    echo "Installer"
                    ;; 
                1) 
                    # manage sites
                    _c=(dialog --clear --backtitle "GYOC Site Manager" --title "GYOC Site Manager" --menu "What would you like to do?" $DHEIGHT $DWIDTH 5)
                    _opts=(1 "Create a New Site"
                             99 "BACK")
                    while true; do
                        _choices=$("${_c[@]}" "${_opts[@]}" 2>&1 >/dev/tty)
                        for _choice in $_choices; do
                            case $_choice in
                                1)
                                    # new site
                                    echo "new site"
                                    ;;
                                99|*)
                                    break;
                                    ;;
                            esac;
                        done;
                    done;
                    sleep 3;
                    ;;
                99|*)
                    dialog --title "Exit Commander" --infobox "We'll see you next time." 7 $DWIDTH
                    sleep 2;
                    clear;
                    exit;
                    ;;
            esac        
        done
    done
fi;
```

Comment: "Please debug this wall of code" is generally not well-accepted here. See the help center on building a [mcve] -- the *shortest possible* code that illustrates a given problem, with anything unnecessary to produce that problem removed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it.
It was the `while true; do` in the secondary menu.

**FINAL CODE**

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ "$(whoami)" != "root" ]; then
    echo "Only root can do this.";
    exit 1;
else

    DWIDTH=40
    DHEIGHT=13
    DIR="$( cd "$( dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" )" && pwd )"; 

    # Silently install dialog
    apt -y install dialog >/dev/null 2>&1

    cmd=(dialog --clear --backtitle "Get You Online Commander" --title "Get You Online Commander" --menu "What would you like to do?" $DHEIGHT $DWIDTH 6)

    options=(0 "Install/Update the Commander"
             1 "Manage Sites"
             99 "EXIT")

    while true; do

        choices=$("${cmd[@]}" "${options[@]}" 2>&1 >/dev/tty)

        # If cancelled, drop the dialog
        if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
            dialog --clear --title "Exit Commander" --infobox "We'll see you next time." 7 $DWIDTH
            sleep 2;
            clear;
            exit;
        fi;

        for choice in $choices; do
            case $choice in
                0)
                    #install/update GYO Commander
                    echo "Installer"
                    ;; 
                1) 
                    # manage sites
                    _c=(dialog --clear --backtitle "GYOC Site Manager" --title "GYOC Site Manager" --menu "What would you like to do?" $DHEIGHT $DWIDTH 5)
                    _opts=(1 "Create a New Site"
                             99 "BACK")
                    #while true; do
                    _choices=$("${_c[@]}" "${_opts[@]}" 2>&1 >/dev/tty)
                    for _choice in $_choices; do
                        case $_choice in
                            1)
                                # new site
                                echo "new site"
                                ;;
                            99|*)
                                break;
                                ;;
                        esac;
                    done;
                    #done;
                    sleep 3;
                    ;;
                99|*)
                    dialog --title "Exit Commander" --infobox "We'll see you next time." 7 $DWIDTH
                    sleep 2;
                    clear;
                    exit;
                    ;;
            esac        
        done
    done
fi;
```

Answer (score 1):

You've been trapped in an infinite loop (unintentionally):

```
  _choices=$("${_c[@]}" "${_opts[@]}" 2>&1 >/dev/tty)
  for _choice in $_choices; do
     case $_choice in
        1)
        # new site
        echo "new site"
        ;;
        99|*)
        break;
        ;;
      esac;
  done;
  ############## FIX ###############
  if [[ "$_choice" == 99 ]]; then
     break
  fi
  ##################################
  done;
  sleep 3
  ;;
```

Comment: This is doing the same thing

Comment: Note, if I throw an `exit` in place of the break, that it exits the entire script, and not just the loop.  But the `break` is just causing the "sub-menu" to refresh

Comment: This is odd. I copied the entire script, edited it like in my answer and when I picked 'back' it worked (had to wait 3 seconds because of the sleep). I even use the same ubuntu version...